Power BI Gantt Chart - Tasks with 3 hierarchy levels and monthly view
I'm using David's Bacci Gantt Chart via Deneb app from the pbix available here
My data is a direct export from MS Project with 3 levels of task hierarchy which I would like to include within the PBI visual.
Now I don't consider myself a JS expert and have been struggling to make the required modifications to work in the code.
Also, I would like to get rid of the progress column for now (which has a red box overlaid on top of the column in the expected output image)
Here is a snippet of the data



Lvl
Unique ID
Task Name
Duration
Start
Finish
Predecessors




0
1
Program-wide
515 days
Mon 11/03/24
Fri 27/02/26



6
253
Project commencement workshop
2 days
Tue 26/03/24
Wed 27/03/24



6
2
Project set-up
30 days
Mon 11/03/24
Fri 19/04/24



6
242
Project Plans, including PMP, EMP, etc.
30 days
Mon 11/03/24
Fri 19/04/24



6
3
Program management
515 days
Mon 11/03/24
Fri 27/02/26



0
9
Project 1
477 days
Fri 5/04/24
Tue 3/02/26



3
28
Preliminary  Investigation
156 days
Fri 5/04/24
Mon 11/11/24



6
25
Start-up meeting
0 days
Fri 5/04/24
Fri 5/04/24
3SS+20 days


6
160
Receipt of information
1 day
Fri 28/06/24
Fri 28/06/24



6
16
Preliminary Site Inspection
20 days
Mon 1/07/24
Fri 26/07/24
9,8,291


6
30
Sampling Analysis Plan
20 days
Mon 1/07/24
Fri 26/07/24
9,8,291


6
23
Final deliverables
0 days
Mon 14/10/24
Mon 14/10/24
19FS+1 day


6
63
Information Session preparation
10 days
Tue 15/10/24
Mon 28/10/24
20


6
62
Information Session
0 days
Mon 28/10/24
Mon 28/10/24
21


6
67
Engagement Summary Report
10 days
Tue 29/10/24
Mon 11/11/24
22


3
29
Detailed Investigation
181 days
Tue 24/09/24
Tue 3/06/25



6
33
Preparation
25 days
Tue 24/09/24
Mon 28/10/24
20FS-15 days


6
34
Field investigations
20 days
Tue 29/10/24
Mon 25/11/24
25,22


6
37
Lab analysis
5 days
Tue 26/11/24
Mon 2/12/24
26


3
53
Risk assessment
181 days
Mon 3/03/25
Tue 11/11/25



6
61
Final deliverables
0 days
Tue 14/10/25
Tue 14/10/25
57


6
64
Information Session preparation
10 days
Wed 15/10/25
Tue 28/10/25
58


6
65
Information Session
0 days
Tue 28/10/25
Tue 28/10/25
59


6
70
Engagement Summary Report
10 days
Wed 29/10/25
Tue 11/11/25
60


0
215
Project 2
491 days
Tue 16/04/24
Tue 3/03/26



3
267
Preliminary  Investigation
170 days
Tue 16/04/24
Mon 9/12/24



6
307
Start-up meeting
0 days
Tue 16/04/24
Tue 16/04/24
3SS+20 days


6
161
Receipt of information
1 day
Fri 28/06/24
Fri 28/06/24



6
231
Preliminary Site Inspection
40 days
Mon 1/07/24
Fri 23/08/24
76,77


6
244
Sampling Analysis Plan
40 days
Mon 1/07/24
Fri 23/08/24
76,77


6
249
Final deliverables
7 days
Mon 9/09/24
Tue 17/09/24
80


6
185
Information Session preparation
3 days
Wed 18/09/24
Fri 20/09/24
81,82


6
250
Information Session
20 days
Mon 23/09/24
Fri 18/10/24
83


6
227
Engagement Summary Report
10 days
Mon 21/10/24
Fri 1/11/24
84


6
236
Detailed Investigation
10 days
Mon 21/10/24
Fri 1/11/24
84


6
281
Preparation
5 days
Mon 4/11/24
Fri 8/11/24
85,86


6
218
Field investigations
0 days
Mon 11/11/24
Mon 11/11/24
87FS+1 day


6
269
Lab analysis
10 days
Tue 12/11/24
Mon 25/11/24
88


6
293
Risk assessment
0 days
Mon 25/11/24
Mon 25/11/24
89


3
333
Final deliverables
181 days
Tue 22/10/24
Tue 1/07/25



6
219
Information Session preparation
25 days
Tue 22/10/24
Mon 25/11/24
88FS-15 days


6
270
Information Session
20 days
Tue 26/11/24
Mon 23/12/24
90,93


6
226
Engagement Summary Report
5 days
Tue 24/12/24
Mon 30/12/24
94



Expected Output:


The progress column is easy to remove but the addition of a third level in the hierarchy would be a significant amount of work unfortunately. If you want just the former, let me know and I'll add an answer

Would you be able to provide some guidance around how to approach adding a new hierarchy level please and I can then try having a crack at it?

Well you would follow the structure that already exists for creating a single level. However, you will need very good Vega knowledge and it is a significant amount of work. If this is your first time using Vega, you might be better finding an alternative option.

Aha, ok.. no worries.
Any pointers around getting started with vega and I'm willing to put in the significant effort and happy to publish it on GitHub if I'm able to make it work.
Any help would be appreciated. TIA

I would try and create some basic charts and work through all the Vega examples to make sure you understand what is going on. Then work through the Vega-Lite examples (transpiling the VL to Vega) to make sure you understand how they've been created. You can also take a look at my GitHub for more sophisticated techniques.

https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/

Cheers, does vega-lite has any overlap with vega (which I thought has been used for the Gantt chart visual)?
I, for some reason, thought vega and vega-lite were completely different?

Vega Lite transpiles to Vega. In the online editor, there is a button to edit the Vega. I'll post a screenshot

Button to transpile to Vega in online editor.


Great, thank you!
